# I get "SSL Connection Error" when trying to connect to a MySql Server from Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, connection

I am trying to work in a connection to a MySql Server database in a powershell script. This is my code:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.26\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll'

$Connection = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]@{
    ConnectionString="server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;uid=user;pwd=password;database=example_db"
}
$Connection.Open()

$sql = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$sql.Connection = $Connection
$sql.CommandText = 'SHOW DATABASES'
$sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
 
# Close the MySQL connection.
$Connection.Close()
```

I downloaded the MySql Connector driver and all, but when I execute the code it gets this error output:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "SSL Connection error."
At C:\Users\Path\To\Code\db_con.ps1:9 char:1        
+ $Connection.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlException
```

I checked the server, user, pwd and everything checks, I can connect using other clients. Also tried using other valid servers and users, but it just throws this same problem.

Comment: Does the server have SSL connections enabled? If not, try adding `SslMode=none` to the connection string.

Comment: Check the certificate, it's store location, its port binding (if applicable).  If you replaced the server address in your example with loop back and you're actually trying to talk to a remote machine then ensure the port is open on the firewalls (hardware or software).

Comment: @AnotherCoder Cool I will make it an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the server have SSL connections enabled? If not, try adding `SslMode=none` to the connection string.